# Prove that $m=[\sqrt{n}+(1/2)]$ for a given conditions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For any real number $x$, let $[x]$ denote the largest integer which is less than or equal to $x$.

Let $N_1=2$, $N_2=3$, $N_3=5$, and so on be the sequence of non-square positive integers. If the $n$th non-square positive integer satisfies $ m²<N_n<(m+1)² $, then show that $ m=[\sqrt{n}+(1/2)] $.

Please help me to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using less-than symbols in text outside math mode (dollar signs) interferes with the HTML coding on this site. That is why half of your question is invisible. Use MathJax (as detailed, for instance, [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) to avoid this.

Answer (score 4):

There are $(m+1)^2-m^2-1=2m$ integers $N_n$ strictly between $m^2$ and $(m+1)^2$. It follows that there are $$2+4+\ldots+2(m-1)=(m-1)m$$ such integers $<m^2$. This means that $m^2<N_n<(m+1)^2$ implies
$$(m-1)m<n\le m(m+1)\ .\tag{1}$$
Since all entries in $(1)$ are integers  we then also have
$$(m-1)m<n-{1\over4}<m(m+1)\ ,$$
or
$$\left(m-{1\over2}\right)^2<n<\left(m+{1\over2}\right)^2\ .$$ From this we conclude that
$$m<\sqrt{n}+{1\over2}<m+1\ ,$$
or
$$m=\left\lfloor \sqrt{n}+{1\over2}\right\rfloor\ .$$

Comment: I know this is a late revert, but shouldn't the inequality after $(1)$ be
$$(m-1)m + \frac{1}{4} < n + \frac{1}{4} < m(m+1) + \frac{1}{4},$$
@ChristianBlatter?

Comment: @JoseArnaldoBebitaDris Not quite.  It's simpler to assume that it was just a sign error.  I've fixed it.