# Under what conditions is it true that $m^2 - a$ is not a square if and only if $(m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2$, where $a>0$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, square-numbers, conjectures, perfect-numbers

> > **Preamble:** The present inquiry is an offshoot of [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121498) from **February 21, 2019**, and ultimately, [*Theorem III.2, page 2*](https://arxiv.org/abs/1206.1548v1) from a paper submitted to a [conference](https://www.dlsu.edu.ph/conferences/snt-congress-2009/) organized by De La Salle University-Manila. I was supposed to deliver a [talk](https://www.dlsu.edu.ph/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/A1905.pdf) regarding this topic on **September 22, 2009**, but I was unable to attend, due to a schedule conflict with my work back then. (My apologies.) The main impetus for this latest MSE question is my having recently found [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2174145).

---

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**

Under what conditions is it true that
$$m^2 - a \text{ is not a square } \iff (m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2,$$
where $a>0$?

---

**MY ATTEMPT**

Let $a>0$.  If $m^2 - a$ satisfies the inequality
$$(m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2$$
then $m^2 - a$ is obviously not a square, as it is between two consecutive squares.

Alas, this is where I get stuck, as I currently do not know how to prove the converse.

**SEARCH FOR COUNTEREXAMPLES**

I ran the following [Pari-GP script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNIADHYU0oGglhmhmmoZiZnFxYWliUapGRZyRgq5CpaaCmpoCjKNgYwtk6xpqxhlp6hQUZeaVaFToKCmAgJJOWmJyCcgyTbhIJbpcpSYIAACbcyRY&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) to search for counterexamples to the converse, however, no output was returned in the range $1 \leq m \leq {10}^{10}$ and $1 \leq a \leq {10}^{10}$:

```
for(x=1, 10000000000, for(y=1, 10000000000, if(!issquare(x^2 - y) && (x^2 - y <= (x-1)^2),print(x,"     ",factor(x),"     ",y,"     ",factor(y)))))
```

**[OPTIMIZED SCRIPT](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA10lEwNDDVUUgD8iptjbQqdBQq4oCCmWkaipnFxYWliUWpGkARBV2FSk2dgqLMvBKNCh0lBRBQ0qnUBAIADDgUNA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) (communicated by [Brian Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/694754))**:

```
for(x=2, 105, for(y=2*x, x^2, if(!issquare(x^2 - y),print(x,"     ",y))))
```

<s>I am therefore led to believe that the criterion indeed holds</s>. (<s>There might have been a bug/error with Pari-GP script processing in Sage Cell Server while I was executing my scripts.</s> I am not an expert on determining computer time/space requirements for running a program/script, but [Brian Moehring](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/694754) has already pointed out in this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692359/under-what-conditions-is-it-true-that-m2-a-is-not-a-square-if-and-only-if?noredirect=1#comment9929785_4692359) that my original script would have caused the servers to fail to give an output for my computational request, so I will have to defer to his opinion.)  As pointed out by [TonyK](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/1508) in a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4692359/under-what-conditions-is-it-true-that-m2-a-is-not-a-square-if-and-only-if#comment9927233_4692359), $m=5$ and $a=15$ is a counterexample to the converse.  (There are *literally* **a lot of them**.)

I would, of course, still be interested in researching the conditions under which the criterion holds.  *Hence, this question.*

---

**CONTEXT**

Specifically, let $N = p^k m^2$ be an odd perfect number with special prime $p$ satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(p,m)=1$.  Then it is known that $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square, granted we could prove that
$p < m$ and $m^2 - p^k$ is not a power of two.

**UPDATE:** Here is a conclusive proof that $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square.  (It turns out that one does not need the extra assumption that $m^2 - p^k$ is not a power of two.)  Assume to the contrary that $m^2 - p^k = n^2$.  Then as proved in [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3121498), we derive $m = (p^k + 1)/2$. Now, in this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3122247/28816), MSE user [FredH](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/82711) proves that the assumption $k \neq 1$ contradicts
$$\gcd(p^{k+1}-1, (p-1) p^k (p^k + 1)^2) \leq (p-1)\gcd(p^{k+1}-1,p^k+1)^2,$$
which follows from
$$\sigma(p^k) \sigma(m^2) = 2p^k m^2 \tag{$**$}$$
and therefore,
$$2(p^{k+1}-1) \sigma(m^2) = (p-1) p^k (p^k + 1)^2.\tag{$*$}$$
Equation $(*)$ is obtained by substituting $m = (p^k + 1)/2$ in Equation $(**)$.  Since $m = (p^k + 1)/2 < p^k$, the assumption $p < m$ implies $k \neq 1$, whereupon we have the implication
$$p < m \implies m^2 - p^k \text{ is not a square}.$$
By the contrapositive, we obtain
$$m^2 - p^k \text{ is a square} \implies m < p \implies k = 1.$$
But then we also know that
$$m^2 - p^k \text{ is a square} \iff m = (p^k + 1)/2 \iff p^k = 2m - 1.$$
But we already know that $k=1$ follows from the given assumption, so that
$$p = 2m - 1.$$
However, Acquaah and Konyagin essentially proved in [(IJNT, 2012)](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/s1793042112500935) that if $p$ is the special prime factor of an odd perfect number $p^k m^2$, then the implication
$$k = 1 \implies p < m\sqrt{3}$$
holds.
Together with the implication
$$k > 1 \implies p < m$$
as proved by Dris in [(JIS, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html), we know unconditionally that
$$p < m\sqrt{3}$$
must hold.  But recall that we have $2m - 1 = p$.  We infer that
$$2m - 1 = p < m\sqrt{3}$$
which is equivalent to
$$m(2 - \sqrt{3}) < 1.$$
This contradicts the fact that $m$ is a humongous number.  (In fact, one can compute the lower bound $m > {10}^{375}$, and this follows from Ochem and Rao's $N > {10}^{1500}$ [(Math. Comp. (2012)](https://www.lirmm.fr/%7Eochem/opn/opn.pdf) and the estimate $p^k < m^2$ by Dris in [(JIS, 2012)](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL15/Dris/dris8.html).)

Hence, $m^2 - p^k$ is **not a square**.  (Additionally, since $4 \mid (m^2 - p^k)$, then $m^2 - p^k$ is likewise **not squarefree**.)

Since $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square and $m^2 - p^k$ is divisible by $4$, then we infer that $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ where we necessarily have $r \geq 2$ and $2^r \neq t$.  (I am not really sure whether the exponential Diophantine equation $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ will force $\gcd(2,t)=1$, if $r \geq 2$ and $2^r \neq t$.)

> > Notice that all of the variables $m, p, k, r,$ and $t$ are actually not known, *a priori*.  But we may try testing heuristics (e.g. inequalities or equations) relating their values, using the Descartes spoof as an "experimental/combinatorial sample".

This particular topic is currently not my cup of tea.  *Hence, this question.*

Comment: That Converse is not true !

Comment: As asked, it is obviously _not_ true. For instance, take $m=5$ and $a=15$. Then $m^2-a=10$ is not a square, but it is not true that $(m-1)^2<m^2-a<m^2$. Perhaps you meant to ask something else?

Comment: Just choose _any_ $a$ less than $2m-1$. If $m$ is large, nearly every such $a$ is a counterexample. I don't know how you missed them all!

Comment: After making my Initial Comment , I have been staring @ that Script , @TonyK , to figure where OP went wrong. I think the numbers are too large & Execution takes time. Changing that to `123` & Executing , I quickly got hundreds of Counter-Examples ! [[ CODE : https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA11FEwNIADHYU0oGglhmhmmoZiZnFxYWliUapGRZyRgq5CpaaCmpoCjKNgYwtk6xpqxhlp6hQUZeaVaFToKCmAgJJOWmJyCcgyTbhIJbpcpSYIAACbcyRY&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ== ]]

Comment: Since $a>0$, the inequality $m^2-a < m^2$ is redundant.

Suppose that $m^2-a$ is not a square. You ask under what conditions you have that $(m-1)^2<m^2-a$. Well, you can say that it holds under the condition that $$(m-1)^2<m^2-a$$ which is equivalent to $2m<a+1$. But this has nothing to do with squares.

Comment: I don't see how there could be any non-trivial conditions that would work here ("trivial" meaning, here, conditions along the lines of "$a$ is the difference between $m^2$ and another square"). I guess it would depend on what you would consider to be trivial, though.

Comment: Questions about integer inequalities are not necessarily problems in number theory. Please don't continue to add the number theory tag.

Comment: @BillDubuque:  The question is about non-square numbers.  It proposes a *criterion* (in the form of an inequality) of when a particular non-square number $m^2 - a$ satisfies that criterion.  I am of the opinion that number theory will play an important part here, especially since I know the multiplicative form of $a$.

Comment: As written you say nothing about the  "multiplicative form of $a$" so there is no reason to believe the problem involves any nontrivial number theory. In any case it is at most an *elementary* number theory problem so as a compromise I will leave it at that for the time being.

Comment: The [number-theory] tag is objectively wrong here.  Just click on the tag to read the tag description.

Comment: The tag [tag:number-theory] is *certainly* incorrect.  I'm on the fence about [tag:elemetnary-number-theory].  Please do not edit the tags again.  Please also try to retain a civil tone.

Comment: *Please* do not keep bumping the question with (trivial) edits. $16$ edits in $9$ hours is too much - it takes away front page exposure from other questions instead of *fairly sharing* such. You can use the [meta sandbox](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/370/formatting-sandbox) to coalesce any edits (this was one of the primary design goals when I created it).

Comment: @Jose There are *many* elementary results of algebra-precalculus and elementary-number-theory that are (often) used in more advanced problems. But that does mean that questions about these elementary results should be tagged with more advanced tags.

Comment: Why does it matter if it is a Diophantine equation?

Comment: Please retain a civil tone.  Yes.  But both the [tag:elementary-number-theory] tag and the [tag:number-theory] tags make reference to Diophantine equations.  So the fact that something relates to Diophantine equations does not, *a priori* imply that it should be tagged with [tag:number-theory].  This tag is reserved for more advanced topics in the field, and this question does not seem to fit that mold.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is absolutely bizarre.  Instead of considering the possibility that your code is bad, you assume there's a bug in the server's handling of your code?  It's possible you were intending for the server to display output as it was generated, while the server seems to write output internally and only show it at the end of execution, but that would still be a user error, not a server-side error.  Then rough estimates show at a minimum it'll take $10^{20}$ cycles and $10^{21}$ bytes.  I don't know any server that allows you that much time or allows you that much space.

Comment: Thank you for your time and attention, @BrianMoehring. Rest assured that I started running the Pari-GP script at a lower range (IIRC, I believe that I started from $[1,1000]$ and then worked gradually upwards.)  By the way, why do you think my code is "bad", if it works for $[1,123]$?

Comment: Additionally, I do know (beforehand) that the server would display the output after the script is done running.  I did not realize that there were too many.  =(

Comment: I don't even know what you mean by "works for $[1,123]$".  If you meant for $x,y$ both in $[1,123]$, then you should have found a lot of counterexamples to your initial claim (a vast majority of the inputs that satisfy $y \geq 2x$ are counterexamples).  [Here, for instance](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA10lEwNDDQUUgD8iptjbQqdBQq4oCCmWkaipnFxYWliUWpGkARBV2FSk2dgqLMvBKNCh0lBRBQ0klLTC4BGaMJF6lEl6vUBAEAlEUdOA==&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==), is some code that shows how ubiquitous the counterexamples are, and it should finish running and output the display in under 30 seconds.

Comment: Note that in my code, we start at $y=2x$ because then we don't need to continuously check whether $x^2 - y < (x-1)^2$ (which is algebraically equivalent to $y > 2x-1$) and it ends at or before $y=x^2$ (so we don't keep checking whether negative numbers are square or not when $x$ is small).  Also, we start at $x=2$ and end at a small enough $x$ so that the time/space requirements of the code are within reason.

Comment: Like I said, I started running the script for the range $[1,1000]$.  (Note that it was [Prem](https://math.stackexchange.com/u/464087) who ran my script for $[1,123]$.)  In the aftermath, I did realize my mistake.

Comment: "Mind if I include a link to your code in a further edit to this question" -- Sure.  I say "my code" only to differentiate it from the code you had posted, but I don't claim any ownership of it.  If you want it to be included indefinitely in the question, you should post it there, as the comments are highly likely to be moved to chat at some point.

Comment: Okay, thank you for giving your consent, Brian.  I have just tried running [your script](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLyy_SqLA10lEwNDAw0FFIA3IrbY20KnQUKuKAoplpGoqZxcWFpYlFqRpAEQVdhUpNnYKizLwSjQodJQUQUNJJS0wuAZmjCRepRJer1AQBAKnZHWg=&lang=gp&interacts=eJyLjgUAARUAuQ==) on the range $m \in [2,1000]$, so I think it is not a problem with my code.  (I am not expert on determining computer time/space requirements for running scripts in Sage Cell Server, so I will have to defer to your opinion.)

Comment: Code is designed to run with appropriately sized parameters.  It is precisely a problem with the code, or at least your implementation of the code, if you intend to run it with larger parameters than it is able to handle.

Comment: The only solution to $m^2-p^k=n^2$ with $\gcd(m,p)=1$ is $m=(p^k+1)/2$, $n=(p^k-1)/2$. This holds as long as $p$ is an odd prime; it doesn't need any assumptions on $p\bmod4$ or $k\bmod4$ or perfection of $p^km^2$.

Comment: Thank you for that information, @GerryMyerson!  We are already aware of that.  (See: [1](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-24/NNTDM-24-4-018-025.pdf), [2](https://nntdm.net/papers/nntdm-26/NNTDM-26-4-033-038.pdf).)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under what conditions is it true that
> $$m^2 - a \text{ is not a square } \iff (m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2,$$
> where $a>0$?

We know it is true that
$$(m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2\implies m^2 - a \text{ is not a square }$$

So, what we want to know is that under what conditions it is true that
$$m^2 - a \text{ is not a square } \implies (m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2\tag2$$

- A proof that $0\lt a\lt 2m-1$ is necessary : Suppose that $m^2-a$ is not a square with $a\geqslant 2m-1$. Then, we have $m^2-a\leqslant m^2-(2m-1)=(m-1)^2$. So, $(m-1)^2\lt m^2-a$ does not hold.
- A proof that $0\lt a\lt 2m-1$ is sufficient : If $m^2 - a$ is not a square with $0\lt a\lt 2m-1$, we have $m^2-a>m^2-(2m-1)=(m-1)^2$ and $m^2-a<m^2$.

Therefore, we can say that under the condition that $0\lt a\lt 2m-1$, it is true that
$$m^2 - a \text{ is not a square } \iff (m - 1)^2 < m^2 - a < m^2$$

---

From what we've got, we can say that under the condition that $p^k\lt 2m-1$, it is true that
$$m^2 - p^k \text{ is not a square } \iff (m - 1)^2 < m^2 - p^k < m^2$$

---

> Since $m^2 - p^k$ is not a square and $m^2 - p^k$ is divisible by $4$, then we infer that $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ where we necessarily have $r \geq 2$ and $2^r \neq t$. (I am not really sure whether the exponential Diophantine equation $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ will force $\gcd(2,t)=1$, if $r \geq 2$ and $2^r \neq t$.)

For each positive integer $N$, if we define $u$ as a non-negative integer satisfying both $2^u\mid N$ and $2^{u+1}\not\mid N$, and $v$ as $\cfrac{N}{2^u}$, then there is only one such pair of integers $(u,v)$, and $u,v$ satisfy
$$N=2^uv,\qquad u\geqslant 0,\qquad v\gt 0,\qquad v\equiv 1\pmod 2$$

**Examples** :

- For $N=24$, $(u,v)=(3,3)$.
- For $N=59$, $(u,v)=(0,59)$.
- For $N=138$, $(u,v)=(1,69)$.
- For $N=1024$, $(u,v)=(10,1)$.

Similarly, if we define $r$ as a non-negative integer satisfying both $2^r\mid m^2-p^k$ and $2^{r+1}\not\mid m^2-p^k$, and $t$ as $\cfrac{m^2-p^k}{2^r}$, then there is only one such pair of integers $(r,t)$, and $r,t$ satisfy
$$m^2-p^k=2^rt,\qquad r\geqslant 2,\qquad t\gt 0,\qquad t\equiv 1\pmod 2$$

So, **if you define $r,t$ as above**, then the integers $r,t$ are not independent from $m,p$ and $k$. The integers $r,t$ are determined by $m,p$ and $k$, so the $r$ means $r(m,p,k)$, and the $t$ means $t(m,p,k)$. Since $t$ is, by the definition, odd, we can say that $\gcd(2,t)=1$.

If you don't define $r,t$ as above (in other words, if you are just writing $m^2-p^k=2^rt,r\geqslant 2,2^r\not=t$), then there are many such pairs $(r,t)$. For example, if $m^2-p^k=192$, then we have $192=2^2\cdot 48=2^3\cdot 24=2^4\cdot 12=2^5\cdot 6=2^6\cdot 3$, so $(r,t)=(2,48),(3,24),(4,12),(5,6),(6,3)$. So, $t$ can be even. On the other hand, if you **define** $r,t$ as above, we get only one pair $(r,t)=(6,3)$ where $t$ is odd.

Comment: Thank you for your comprehensive and detailed answer, @mathlove!  So just to confirm, essentially you are saying that if I consider $m^2 - p^k = 2^r t$ with $\gcd(2,t)=1$, then although the variables $r$ and $t$ are determined by $m, p,$ and $k$, they are **UNIQUE**?

Comment: @Jose Arnaldo Bebita Dris : Yes.

Comment: My profuse thanks to you for the affirmation, @mathlove.  =)

Comment: I have just awarded the **(500)** bounty for this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4692359/28816) to your [subsequent answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4694154/28816), @mathlove. Again, my profuse thanks for your time and attention. Enjoy!  =)